# sortable list using jquery ui not passing updated list order

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I am following the sortable lists railscast and got everything working except when I sort, the same (original) order gets passed to the update method each time, so it doesn't update the true order.

Here's the code:

In the view:

```
%tbody#lineup{"data-update-url" => sort_lineups_url}
      - @lineup.pieces.each_with_index do |piece, index|
        = content_tag_for :tr, piece do
          = render 'piece', :piece => piece, :index => index
```

and pieces.js.coffee:

```
jQuery ->
  $('#lineup').sortable(
    axis: 'y'
    update: ->
      $.post($(this).data('update-url'), $(this).sortable('serialize'))
  );
```

sort and show methods of lineupscontroller:

```
  def show
    @lineup = Lineup.find_by_user_id(current_user.id)
    @pieces = @lineup.pieces.order("position")
  end

  def sort
    params[:piece].each_with_index do |id, index|
      current_user.lineup.pieces.update_all({position: index+1}, {id: id})
    end
    render nothing: true
  end
```

and the update request:

```
Started POST "/lineups/sort" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-06-24 20:06:14 -0700
Processing by LineupsController#sort as */*
  Parameters: {"piece"=>["8", "2", "1", "4", "3", "7"]}
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 2 LIMIT 1
  Lineup Load (0.6ms)  SELECT `lineups`.* FROM `lineups` WHERE `lineups`.`user_id` = 2 LIMIT 1
  SQL (2.9ms)  UPDATE `pieces` INNER JOIN `piece_lineups` ON `pieces`.`id` = `piece_lineups`.`piece_id` SET `position` = 1 WHERE `piece_lineups`.`lineup_id` = 3 AND `pieces`.`id` = 8
  SQL (0.6ms)  UPDATE `pieces` INNER JOIN `piece_lineups` ON `pieces`.`id` = `piece_lineups`.`piece_id` SET `position` = 2 WHERE `piece_lineups`.`lineup_id` = 3 AND `pieces`.`id` = 2
  SQL (0.6ms)  UPDATE `pieces` INNER JOIN `piece_lineups` ON `pieces`.`id` = `piece_lineups`.`piece_id` SET `position` = 3 WHERE `piece_lineups`.`lineup_id` = 3 AND `pieces`.`id` = 1
  SQL (0.5ms)  UPDATE `pieces` INNER JOIN `piece_lineups` ON `pieces`.`id` = `piece_lineups`.`piece_id` SET `position` = 4 WHERE `piece_lineups`.`lineup_id` = 3 AND `pieces`.`id` = 4
  SQL (0.6ms)  UPDATE `pieces` INNER JOIN `piece_lineups` ON `pieces`.`id` = `piece_lineups`.`piece_id` SET `position` = 5 WHERE `piece_lineups`.`lineup_id` = 3 AND `pieces`.`id` = 3
  SQL (0.5ms)  UPDATE `pieces` INNER JOIN `piece_lineups` ON `pieces`.`id` = `piece_lineups`.`piece_id` SET `position` = 6 WHERE `piece_lineups`.`lineup_id` = 3 AND `pieces`.`id` = 7
  Rendered text template (0.0ms)
```

so each time i drag+drop the list, it sends the same order again. what am I doing wrong that the params isn't passing the right, updated order?
    Completed 200 OK in 2757ms (Views: 1.0ms | ActiveRecord: 6.7ms)

```
%tr{:style => 'height: 60px;'}
  %td{:style => 'text-align: center;'}
    %h5= index + 1
  %td{:style => 'padding-left: 10px;'}
    %h5= "#{piece.name} - #{piece.id}"
  %td{:style => 'text-align: center;'}
    %h5= piece.category
  %td{:style => 'padding-left: 10px;'}
    %h5= piece.description
  %td{:style => 'padding-left: 10px;'}
    %h5= @lineup.get_piece_status(piece.id)
  %td.pop{:style => 'text-align: center;', :rel => 'popover',:'data-title' => piece.name, :'data-placement' => 'bottom', :'data-content' => image_tag(piece.photo.url(:small))}
    = image_tag(piece.photo.url(:tiny))
  %td{:style => 'text-align: center;'}
    - unless ['Preparing', 'Shipped', 'Arrived'].include?(@lineup.get_piece_status(piece.id))
      = form_for(@lineup, :html => {:id => "remove#{piece.id}", :style => "margin-bottom: 0px;"}) do |f|
        = f.hidden_field(:piece_id, :value => piece.id)
        = link_to 'x', '#', :onclick=>"document.getElementById('remove#{piece.id}').submit(); return false;"
```

Comment: What is the html id set to for each of the table rows?

Comment: I don't have html ids set for each table row, maybe that is the issue? how do I add that? (i added my table row code to the origin post)

Comment: Actually, content_tag_for sets the html ids for you, so that doesn't seem to be the problem. It could have something to do with the positions being cached. Have a look at the refreshPositions method: $(this).sortable( "refreshPositions" )